# How do I undo `brew link --force openssl` on mac yosemite

Tags: macos, homebrew

I had some issues while trying to upgrade the brew formulas with php54. I found on github some suggestions to deal with the [openssl php brew bug](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1181). Some of them suggested to run `brew link openssl --force` and I did that but at the end the issue was somewhere else and was not related to openssl.

So how do I undo `brew link openssl --force`. I tried to see what this does with `brew link openssl --dry-run` but the output is:

```
Warning: openssl is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.
```

and obviously not the  one that I expect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
brew unlink openssl
```

That will remove the symlinks that were created when running `brew link`.

Comment: Ok. I did that. Thanks. `Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j... 0 symlinks removed`

Comment: But do you have an idea on how to see the changes that link would make, because when I fist run the link command I got this output: `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1j... 1146 symlinks created`